# get data in php from jquery serialize array

Tags: php, jquery

I am new with php and I want to get form data in php from jQuery serialize array. In php I am not able to get this data in proper format.
Here how I am passing this data from jquery

```
var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
```

In php I have implemented `json_decode` function but I am still getting this array in not useful format.

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);
```

It is returning form data in this format

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => fname
        [value] => MyFirstName
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => lname
        [value] => MyLastName
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => phone
        [value] => 324242
    )
 [3] => Array
    (
        [name] => institution_name[]
        [value] => institution
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => degree_name[]
        [value] => Graduated
    )
```

How I can get data properly from this array so that I can use this properly. There are more then 50 input fields in my form and I have few fields like degree_name[] so there can be more then one degree_name[] input fields so how I will be able to fetch data when I will have multiple input fields with the same name. I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for if I'm reading the question right is:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);

foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "{$row['name']}: {$row['value']}";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

for multiple input fields with the same name
use array name in input field,
for example:

```
<input name="degree_name[]" type="text">
```

Comment: I am already using this but I have asked a different question above. I want to get these input values in php.